# Sublime Text 2 & Zen Coding : How to write multiple nesting

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2

Output :

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="body">
    <hello>
        <world></world>
    </hello>
</div>
```

Corresponds to :

```
div#header+div#body>hello>world
```

What command to use to get the output like below  ?

```
<div id="header">
    <hello2>
        <world2></world2>
    </hello2>
</div>
<div id="body">
    <hello>
        <world></world>
    </hello>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to create groups of nested elements:

`(#header>hello2>world2)+(#body>hello>world)`

Actually, in this example, the second set of parenthesis isn't necessary, because the first set creates the first group, which is enough:

`(#header>hello2>world2)+#body>hello>world`